# How do I encrypt a file during transit/Copy

Tags: file-copying

I am currently using a FileOp.Copy routine.

```
ShellFileOperation.DoFileOperation(sourceFile,
                                   DestinationFile,
                                   "Moved Files",
                                   FileOp.Copy,
                                   FileOpFlags.NoCopySecurityAttributes | FileOpFlags.NoErrorUI,
                                   f1);
```

I now have a policy that states: "must be encrypted in transit"

Is there a way to ensure that this routine is encrypting the file between computer A and computer B?  Is there a different routine that would give me this function?

Thanks,
Mike

I don't know what I'm expecting.

Just want a solution that would make the paranoid crowd happy.

Comment: HTTPS encrypts traffic, HTTP does not.   You could encrypt the file before sending, then decrypt it after it arrives.  Otherwise, you need to edit the question to include the platforms of the client and server, and whether you can change the code of both.

Comment: ^ of note, in order to use HTTPS you need an SSL cert. installed on the server. If you don't use it, it allows man in the middle attacks as the data is passed from your computer on its way to the remote server.  You could also encrypt the data, AND use SSL for double protection, but you would have to build an unencrypt on the other other end to catch and validate the data.